# Run dnsmasq as DHCP server from inside a Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, dhcp, dnsmasq

I'm trying to get dnsmasq to operate as a DHCP server inside a Docker container, issuing DHCP addresses to machines on the host's physical network. I'm using the Alpine Linux 6MB container from https://hub.docker.com/r/andyshinn/dnsmasq/.

It works fine as a DNS server on port 53 on the host machine, however there is nothing listening on port 67/udp, which is where I'm expecting DHCP to be. I use 
`dhcping 192.168.2.2`, but get "no answer". `telnet 192.168.2.2 67` returns "Connection refused".

My dnsmasq.conf file in the container looks like this:

```
interface=eth0
user=root
domain-needed
bogus-priv
no-resolv
local=/mydomain.io/
no-poll
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
no-hosts
addn-hosts=/etc/dnsmasq_static_hosts.conf
expand-hosts
domain=mydomain.io
dhcp-range=192.168.2.10,192.168.2.250,255.255.255.0,192.168.2.255,5m
# Have windows machine release on shutdown
dhcp-option=vendor:MSFT,2,1i
# No default route
dhcp-option=3
```

The host machine has a static address of 192.168.2.2.

I start the container like this:

`docker run -d --name dns -p 192.168.2.2:67:67/udp -p 192.168.2.2:53:53/udp sitapati/dns`

There is no firewall on this machine, which is running Ubuntu 16.04.

Things I've thought of/tried:

- is it because eth0 in the container has an address on a completely different subnet? (`docker inspect` tells me it's 172.17.0.2 on the bridged interface)
- does it need to use `--net host`? I tried that, and it still didn't work.

Comment: I eventually used isc-dhcpd. That works. Still not sure why the dnsmasq one doesn't work. 

Here's the working DHCP server inside a Docker container:
https://github.com/jwulf/docker-dhcpd

Comment: Why was this question down-voted?

Comment: Don't know @igal. The question is legit, well written and indeed: Docker documentation is really bad on this topic and frequently changing. One of the main reasons why this often doesn't work seems to be that net=host ist not supportet on (legacy) windows containers. In the new "Docker for Windows" (Windows 10 / 2016 and higher) release however this seems to be a supported thing but it still seems not to work that well. But you said you're on Linux. So that must be something different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the container will have its own interfaces on a virtual subnet (the `docker0` bridge network). So it will be trying to offer addresses on that subnet.

Using `--net host` worked for me, I got the DHCP server working using something like the following command:

```
docker run --name dnsmasq2 -t -v /vagrant/dnsmasq.conf:/opt/dnsmasq.conf -p 67:67/udp --net host centos
```

`--net host` ensures that the container appears to using the host's networking stack rather than its own.

```
dnsmasq -q -d --conf-file=/opt/dnsmasq.conf --dhcp-broadcast
```

I also needed to add the `--dhcp-broadcast` flag to dnsmasq within the container to get it to actually broadcast `DHCPOFFER` messages on the network. For some reason, dnsmasq was trying to unicast the `DHCPOFFER` messages, and it was using ARP to try to get an address that had not yet been assigned.